# Regular Expression to match any string consisting of letters,digits and apostrophes. But exclude underscores

Tags: python, expression, python-re

I'm desperately searching for a regular expression in Python, only using the `re` library. The expression should divide a text into single strings consisting of letters, digits and apostrophes from any language.

For example:

- `"Test, this is a String 123!"` should be: `["Test", "this", "is", "a", "String", "123"]`
- `"λάκιäsañ"` should be: `["λάκιäsañ"]`
- `"not_underscores"` should be: `["not", "underscores"]`

I tried so far:

```
[\w\']+
```

Here is a string like `"included_Underscores"` not divided in `"included"` `"underscores"`.

```
([^\W_]+(?:\')*)
```

Here is everything recognized as it should, but characters after `"'"` are separated

```
([\w\'](?<=[^_]))+
```

Here, the last char of a word is separated

Answer (score 1):

`\w` includes underscore. If you want a different definition, you need to spell it out.  Fortunately, in this case, it's easy to define a complement consisting of any non-`\w`, non-underscore character, or apostrophe.

```
re.findall(r"(?:[^\W_]|')+", text)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"(?:[^\W_]|')+", "Test, this is a String 123!")
['Test', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'String', '123']
>>> re.findall(r"(?:[^\W_]|')+", "λάκιäsañ")
['λάκιäsañ']
>>> re.findall(r"(?:[^\W_]|')+", "not_underscores")
['not', 'underscores']
>>> re.findall(r"(?:[^\W_]|')+", "don't worry, be happy")
["don't", 'worry', 'be', 'happy']
```

An obvious drawback is that single quotes around a string will also be included.

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?:[^\W_]|')+", "'scare quotes' are scary")
["'scare", "quotes'", 'are', 'scary']
```

Sometimes they are correctly part of the word, too.

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?:[^\W_]|')+", "vi flytt' int'")
['vi', "flytt'", "int'"]
```

Comment: Ref https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/swedish-vi-flytt-int.912301/

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
import re


def splitIt(line: str) -> list[str]:
    line = re.sub(r"[_]", " ", line)
    line = re.sub(r"[^\w']+$", "", line)
    line = re.sub(r"^[^\w']+", "", line)
    res = re.split(r"[^\w']+", line)
    return res


assert splitIt("Test, this is a String 123") == [
    "Test",
    "this",
    "is",
    "a",
    "String",
    "123",
]

assert splitIt("asdf λάκιäsañ 123") == [
    "asdf",
    "λάκιäsañ",
    "123",
]

assert splitIt("not_underscores") == [
    "not",
    "underscores",
]


assert splitIt("not' underscores") == [
    "not'",
    "underscores",
]
```